# Angular problem with routing empty routes

Tags: angular, routes

I have a problem with my routes in my application, I don't know why if I have one empty route in one module it redirects to that instead of home.

These are the routes in my app module.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: LandingComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {
    path: 'products/x',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: XComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products/y',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: YComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products/Z',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./z/z.module').then(m => 
    m.ZModule) 
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
```

And these are the routes in my z module.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: ZComponent
    }
];
```

My problem is when I entered my http://localhost:4200/ it displays my Z components instead of my lading component. I already tried to remove the pathMatch from the Z module or from the child route, but I get the same result.

**********************************EDIT*******************

Per the recomendation below in the comments I already tried separating the `products` routes and put them as child routes and didn't work

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: LandingComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  {
      path: 'products',
      children: [
          {
              path: 'x',
              pathMatch: 'full',
              canActivate: [AuthGuard],
              component: XComponent
          },
          {
              path: 'y',
              pathMatch: 'full',
              canActivate: [AuthGuard],
              component: YComponent
          },
          {
              path: 'z',
              pathMatch: 'full',
              canActivate: [AuthGuard],
              loadChildren: () => import('./z/z.module').then(m => m.ZModule)
          },
      ]
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
```

Comment: Hello, did you try to put out `products` routes to it's own group? And next one proposal, did you try to remove slash before `home` in `redicerctTo` property? 'redirectTo: 'home''

Comment: post the content of app.module

Comment: @dpischalkda How would be the approach of puting `products` routes by it's own? I just removed the slash in `redirectTo: 'home'` but it's doesn't work

Comment: @RicardoSanchezSantos, I meant move `products` routes to it's own group. Like:
{
path: 'products',
children: [{
    path: 'x',
    ...,
}, {
    path: 'y',
    ...,
}],
...
}

Comment: @dpischalkda I just tried and didn't work

Comment: @RicardoSanchezSantos I tried to reproduce simplified similar in stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-epsxzf?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts, but it works ok.

What is in your console, maybe some errors?
How guards passes, did you observe by code execution?

Comment: be sure to remove the `ZModule` from the `AppModule`.